# How to interface an IR sensor(infrared receiver) with a linux desktop using USB port

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, kodi, infrared

I have an [**IR sensor**](https://www.adafruit.com/product/157) and I have successfully connected it with RaspberryPI and Ardunio in the past using GPIO pins.

I am thinking of **connecting the same sensor(IR sensor) with my Linux desktop using the USB port**. Connecting it with raspberry PI was straightforward using the GPIO and then reading the input value at a particular GPIO pin.

In my Linux system, I am thinking to use a `USB TO Serial TTL Converter Module]` [USB to TTL Serial Cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) or [PL2303 USB UART Board](https://www.ebay.com/itm/251046472000).

**Goal**: My end goal is to use an IR remote to control the media centre [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/) installed in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using an IR remote, IR receiver sensor.

I am aware of software/libraries such as [**lirc**](https://www.lirc.org/) and have successfully used it in RaspberryPi OS and [Libreelec os](https://libreelec.tv/). All the blogs/articles that I found on the internet pointed me to buy a USB IR receiver. If you can please tell me the steps involved in achieving the above goal. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spare Raspbery Pi, you can easily write a script that will detect commands from the IR and send them to the Ubuntu box via ssh or via HTTP webhooks. I would recommend that this would be a Pi 0W unless being used for some other purpose, as a normal Pi consumes too much power and is somewhat wasteful (in money & resources).

If you don't mind spending $15 on adafruit and are somewhat comfortable with soldering (the headers are not soldered on), I'd recommend this adafruit chip: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264

It's relatively trivial to code with adafruit python libraries: https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-any-computer-with-ft232h

And it simply connects to your computer via a USB C female port and connects it to your IR gpio device.